# A question regarding work done by tension force in a simple pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

[image]

Consider the picture given below to show the free body diagram of a simple pendulum going to and fro and not a conical pendulum. I have read in my physics book that work done by tension force is zero as force is perpendicular to displacement but does the horizontal component of tension do work as it is in the same x-direction of the displacement? The formula of work $W = FS \cos\theta$ tells us to take force in the direction of displacement.

Comment: Is the path of the bob a circle in the horizontal plane?

Comment: Yes it is in a horizontal plane like how a simple pendulum would move

Comment: @AJknight A simple pendulum moves in a *vertical* plane. It moves up and down as well as from side to side. In other words there is a displacement in the y direction as well as in the x direction.

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to say.There are two components of tension so will the horizontal component of tension contribute to work done as the work done due to vertical component is zero

Comment: @AJknight The vertical displacement is not zero, so why do you think the work done by the vertical component of the tension is zero ? The work done by the vertical component of tension is equal and opposite to the work done by the horizontal component - see R.W.Bird's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As the pendulum swings down, the horizontal component of the tension does positive work, and the vertical component does negative work. The total work done by the tension is zero:
$$
[T\sin(θ)][(ds)\cos(θ)] – [T\cos(θ)][(ds)\sin(θ)] = 0\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is a simple pendulum (a pendulum swinging back and forth and allowed to change height), or the circular pendulum that you seem to be talking about (the bob moving in a horizontal circle), the tension force is always perpendicular to the direction of motion.  That means the work doen by the tension force is zero, *full stop*.  You don't need to think about the components of the tension at all, because you can *see* that the tension force is perpendicular to the direction of motion at all times.

If you want to think in terms of components, for a vertical pendulum, see [the other answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/710857/83835). For the horizontal pendulum, note that at the moment in time shown in your diagram, the $x$ component of the tension force points toward the center of the circle, but the direction of motion is *perpendicular* to the plane of the page, and so the $T_x$ doesn't contribute to work.  Similarly, the vertical component of the tension *also* is perpendicular to the direction of motion.  So no work done by tension.